# How can I parse a custom string as a timezone aware datetime?

Tags: python-3.x, pytz

How can I parse

```
18 January 2022, 14:50 GMT-5
```

as a timezone aware datetime.

```
pytz.timezone('GMT-5')
```

fails.
It appears I may need to parse the GMT part, and manually apply the 5 hours offset post parsing?

Comment: Are all your dates "GMT-5" by any chance?

Comment: no it varies, but it seems to be either GMT or UTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm How about maybe:

```
import re
import datetime
foo = "18 January 2022, 14:50 GMT-5"
bar = re.sub(r"[+-]\d+$", lambda m: "{:05d}".format(100 * int(m.group())), foo)
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(bar, "%d %B %Y, %H:%M %Z%z" ))
```

I think that gives you:

`2022-01-18 14:50:00-05:00`